# id for each element showing undefined or 0 not being assigning different id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign a id to each link in my list like this,

```
for (var j = start; j < stop; j++) { 
    link = linkBase + json[j].relatedItemId;

    $('#citations').append('<li><a href="' + link + '" id="num" + j>' + 
        json[j].title + '</a></li>'); 
        alert($('a').attr('id'));
}
```

it keeps giving me undefined or 0? Should I use $.each outside of the for loop instead?

I was trying to use the for loop for two purposes but maybe that's not such a great idea?

*EDIT***

If I put my for loop inside of a function like,

```
// Loop function for each section
var loopSection = function(start, stop) {

// Http setup for all links
var linkBase = "http://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/";

// Link for citation information
var link = "";

for (var j = start; j < stop; j++) { 
    link = linkBase + json[j].relatedItemId;

    var $anchor = $("<a>", {
        href: link, 
        id: "id" + j, 
        text: json[j].title
    })   

    // .parent() will get the <li> that was just created and append to the first citation 
    element                                              
    $anchor.appendTo("<li>").parent().appendTo("#citations");
    }
}
```

I'm not able to access the id from outside of the function

```
$('#citations').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var print = ($(this).attr('id'));

    alert(print);
});
```

Comment: what is the value of `json`?

Comment: That alert will just give you the "id" of the very first `<a>` on the page.

Comment: You'd be way better off instantiating the `<li><a/></li>` structure in an object, rather than appending it in-line like that, especially if you have lots of them.

Comment: 1) `.append('<li><a href="' + link + '" id="num' + j + '">'` 2) `$('a').attr('id')` will return the id of the first anchor tag on the page, always.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks that's what I was wondering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form is much cleaner:

```
for (var j = start; j < stop; j++) { 
    link = linkBase + json[j].relatedItemId;

    $("<a>", {
        href: link, 
        id:'num' + j, 
        text: json[j].title
    }).appendTo("<li>")
      .parent()               // get the <li> we just made
      .appendTo("#citations");
}
```

If you want a reference to the anchor tag you created, do this:

```
for (var j = start; j < stop; j++) { 
    link = linkBase + json[j].relatedItemId;

    var $anchor = $("<a>", {
        href: link, 
        id:'num' + j, 
        text: json[j].title
    });

    $anchor.appendTo("<li>").parent().appendTo("#citations");
}
```

Comment: Wow, ok Shmiddty that makes sense just didn't know I could it that way. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @jc72 It's not very well documented, and the documentation there is on it isn't very easy to find.

Comment: I was thinking I'd never seen that before, where the heck did he get that haha. I'm teaching this stuff to myself so I've seen a lot of examples on the web, but not like that one.

Comment: So it's basically creating a anchor object with the attributes and appending to each <li>, and the .parent() then allows it to be appended to the citations, correct?

Comment: Not appending to "each <li>", it is creating an `<li>` and appending the anchor to it. The context will still be the anchor, which is why I call `parent()` changing the context to the newly created `<li>`, which I then append to the first element with the id of `citations`

Comment: Hey Shmiddty, I put the loop inside a function like var loopSection = function(start, stop) {} but how do i access the id of a link outside of the function if it's clicked??

Comment: @jc72 `this.id`? I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: I did an edit to the original problem to show how I've tried to changed the code. Basically I'm not able to get the id of any link while outside the function unless I'm selecting the right element?

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is to display the id name for the link that's been clicked, which I assume (wrongly) can simply be done by assigning each link an id and then saying if a citation is clicked give me that id. However it seems a lot more complicated haha

Comment: It would probably be better to post your follow up question as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code (id="num" + j..)

However,You should do this by the code (avoiding syntax error and giving a better performance)

```
for (var j = start; j < stop; j++)
{
    var link = linkBase + json[j].relatedItemId;

    $('#citations').append($(document.createElement('li'))
                           .append($(document.createElement('a'))
                                   .attr('href', link)
                                   .attr('id', 'num' + j)
                                   .html(json[j].title)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer from Schmiddty but, for the sake of completeness

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  var link = "someLink.htm";
  $('#citations').append('<li><a href="' + link + '" id="num' + j + '">'+ 'click here' + '</a></li>'); 
  alert($('#citations a:last').attr('id'));
}
```

I've only changed your variable to make it work on its own on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kentcoast/9r9wL/) as a demo

Comment: Yeah Schmiddty's answer performs great although I was still trying to figure out how to do it the way it looks in your fiddle. Just couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong even if it didn't work well I just wanted to know, so much thanks!